# Merge tow excel file with some parameters

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge, sum

[here is my problem, i have tow excel file i want to merge them and sum only value of column C if the value of column A is matched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPtNa.png)

Comment: so you want to union the two files?

Comment: Yes,  but not only merge the tow file,  i also want to merge some values and ignore others

Comment: .csv files or excel .xls/xlsx?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how someone could iterate through multiple files and combine values. You will see how to open a file, read it, and manipulate the data. The example below is a rough example and could be made much more elegant but with out proper context this may get you off to the right start. The example assumes there is and always will be only three columns. My output below shows just printing the example final values out but you could just as easily wright them to a new file.

```
#create dict to track values
dict = {}
files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']

for file in files:
  with open(file) as rfile:
    next(rfile) #skip first line
    
    for row in rfile: 
      row = row.split(' ')
      
      #get rows column values
      a_value = float(row[0].strip())
      b_value = float(row[1].strip())
      c_value = float(row[2].strip())
      
      #a column value isn't in dictionary
      if a_value not in dict.keys(): 
        dict[a_value] = [b_value, c_value]
      else: 
        dict[a_value][1] += c_value

    

print("A B C")
for key, val in dict.items():
  print(key,val[0],val[1])
```

example stnd out from above:

```
A B C
112.0 5.0 300.0
110.0 10.0 300.0
1111.0 2.0 2222.0
115.0 2.0 400.0
116.0 2.0 122.0
```